# Creating a link to name changing directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, shell, shell-script

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 installed using wubi + Win7.

I'm trying to create a link to "my documents" directory which located in my C drive:
C:\Users\Myuser\My Documents\

Since the Ubuntu is installed in D:\, which is the "host", my C drive is accessible via /media/some_changing_hex. This hex get changed each time I restart my machine. So I need, somehow, to create a link that uses regex OR a link that somehow gets the the first (in this case - only) subdirectory in /media (something like all_subdirectories[0]).

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You add an entry to `/etc/fstab` that mounts it to the same location under `/mnt` each time.

Comment: http://bit.ly/M6cyya